# VS Code crash reporting

Tags: visual-studio-code

According to telemetry documentation the `telemetry.telemetryLevel` user setting controls what type of telemetry data is collected, **including crash reports**.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/telemetry

However, the FAQ page has a 'How to disable crash reporting' section refers to the `enable-crash-reporter` setting in the `argv.json` file.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_how-to-disable-crash-reporting

What is the difference between those settings?

Comment: Don't associate link for here and there, please. Just make your question concise

Comment: In addition, when I turn off `"enable-crash-reporter": false,` and restart VSCode, it reverts that settings to true. Suspicious.